# How to get web service proxy url from web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a solution that contains 2 projects - website project and class library project.

class library project call a webservice, so it has a webservice reference and webservice proxy created automatically when I added the webservice reference.

website project instantiates a class library and invokes a method that calls the webservice.

Question - how to configure a webservice url in website project's web.config and use it when calling the webservice ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you created the service reference in the library, it added an app.config file, with the appropriate configuration information. All you need to do is copy that stuff into the web.config of your web project.